# Internet Connection Error - Connection Fails

Tags: networking, internet, troubleshooting, internet-connection

My internet seems to be working but is not. My screen shows 4 bars (PC). However whenever I try to go to Amazon or any other major websites, apart from all things Google and Stack Exchange, it does not load the page.

Is there a specific reason why I am unable to connect to certain websites? And how will I be able to solve this?

I might not have asked the question in the right site. So if you could migrate it, it would be nice. I thought between Super User and Server Fault, but couldn't pinpoint the location.

[image]

---

**EDIT:** It's been happening for a week now.

**FYI:** I have asked on Server Fault, however, they vehemently rejected the question right away. :-(

**EDIT 2:** Tried everything with Zain's answer, but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried opening CMD and typing **ipconfig /flushdns**

Comment: Yes, and it is still not working.

Comment: What actually happens when the webpage doesn't load (i.e. error message)? Have you only tried one web browser?

Comment: @zain.ali I added a picture.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Flush the DNS Cache**

In some cases, flushing the DNS cache may help. You can flush the DNS by holding down the Windows key on your keyboard and pressing R to bring up the Run box. Then type `ipconfig /flushdns` and press Enter. You already mentioned that you've done this but I've added it anyway.

Still no luck? Try. . .

**2. Checking if Spyware Has Modified Your HOSTS file**

To check it, go to `Start > Run`.
Do the following:
Windows 8, 7, Vista, XP and Windows 2000 users type:

`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

Open the file called HOSTS using NOTEPAD or WORDPAD.
Each entry will look something like the following:

```
0 pagead.googlesyndication.com
0.0.0.0 ad.doubleclick.net
```

Entries like this will block access to the sites listed. Look for entries like this referring to any web site you may not be able to access and delete them. You may also have to run a spyware scan using an utility like **MalwareBytes** or **Spybot**.

*Note: For most users this file is blank. Unless you have any type of special configuration for systems on your network, the HOSTS file isn’t normally used. It is most likely safe to remove all entries from this file.*

**3. Firewall Software is Blocking Access**

Disable your firewall.  By disabling it and trying to access the web we can determine if the firewall is causing the issue.

If you are able to access websites that you were unable to before, then the issue is your firewall. Check if both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` are enabled.

**4. Problems with Sites that Use SSL**

If the problem is only with sites that require a secure or SSL connection, you might want to troubleshoot the browsers ability to connect using SSL. If you can’t view this website, SSL problems are likely to blame.

For Internet Explorer read [this article.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813444)

If you have a firewall, make sure that it allows communication over port 443.

Follow [this link](http://support.mozy.co.uk/articles/en_US/FAQ/How-to-add-Port-443-to-the-Windows-Firewall-in-Windows-7) to see how to enable port 443.

Keep us updated!

Comment: How do I do step 4? Don't understand what port 443 and how to **allow** it.

Comment: Think of ports as lanes (as in driving). Each lane will allow the computer to do different things. There are many different lanes. For example, one lane can be for browsing, another lane could be for emailing etc. If a lane is blocked, the computer will not be able to perform whatever that lane is designed to do. Example, if the email lane is blocked, the computer will not be able to use the email lane. Once the lane is unblocked, it will be able to send emails. There is a lane for secure browsing, this lane is called **Port 443**. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: The funny thing is, that I cannot connect to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Time and Date SSL Connection Errors

Connection errors can occur when your time and date are not correctly set on the computer.

This is due to the computer being unable to verify the identity of the website via its SSL Certificate as when the time and date do not match it assumes it is a forgery and closes the connection.

**How to change Time and Date**

Please ensure that the time and date on your machine are 100% correct.

Instructions on setting the time and date on a Windows 7 computer can be found on Microsoft's website at the following link:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/set-clock

As you cannot visit many websites I have copied the contents of the pages relevant information below:

> Your computer's clock is used to record the time whenever you create or modify files on your computer. You can change the clock's time and time zone.

1. Open Date and Time by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Clock, Language, and Region, and then clicking Date and Time.
2. Click the Date and Time tab, and then click Change date and time.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. In the Date and Time Settings dialog box, do one or more of the following:
4. To change the hour, double-click the hour, and then click the arrows to increase or decrease the value.
5. To change the minutes, double-click the minutes, and then click the arrows to increase or decrease the value.
6. To change the seconds, double-click the seconds, and then click the arrows to increase or decrease the value.
7. When you have finished changing the time settings, click OK.
8. To change the time zone, click Change time zone.
9. In the Time Zone Settings dialog box, click your current time zone in the drop-down list, and then click OK.

**Your situation**

I have looked at the time and date in the picture you have posted but am unable to deduce whether or not it is incorrect as I do not know where you are located or when the screenshot was in fact taken.

**Further Solutions to this problem**

If this does solve your issue then it may be that your computer is losing its time and date. If this is the case a solution must be found or else the scenario will continue to happen. This is usually caused be a flat CMOS battery, this is a small watch battery inside the computer, often a CR2032, that keeps the time amongst other small settings when no power is being supplied to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

This occured to me as well. For me it was a problem with ISP. I went to the router settings and just edited and saved everything as it is. That fixed it for me.

Did you try it with another PC/OS or something?